# How do I refactor procedural RPC PHP to object oriented?

Tags: php, oop, refactoring, legacy, procedural

I have a legacy API in PHP that I need to refactor. The request must include an operation (eg. 'get_some_data') which is determined in a massive if/else sequence. All refactoring recommendations I find online consist of converting procedural to OOP, but in this application there is not really a logical grouping of the operations.

Is there some best practises (or good tips) you have for refactoring a project like this? The final goal is full automated test coverage.

Comment: Please provide more details about your project, like snippet of code so we could find what to refactor.

Comment: I would start by replacing repeated code with function calls, grouping them into classes. That would also give complete knowledge of the code, which will help with reorganising it.

Comment: I can't really upload the code here, as it's proprietary, but it goes something like this:

    if($_POST[operation]==5){
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE users VALUES (" . 
    $_POST[username] . ");
        echo 1;
    } else if($_POST[operation]==6) { /* ... */ }

and so forth. Horrible code, but I have determined the actions of the numeric codes.

Comment: Typo: "INSERT INTO users", but you get the gist.